# Laravel Localhost or pretty url not working

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, laravel-routing, pretty-urls

I have installed composer on windows 8 and i am using the webserver xampp,

I did the comand composer global require

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

I even configure env path for composer like this

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

Then created the project like this

```
Laravel new myproject
```

I check the file .htaccess in my public folder of my laravel project,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have checked the module activation for url rewriting in apache httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

then i test it and i typed many urls and it gives a page not found ERROR !

Here are the url tested:

- localhost/laravel/
- localhost/laravel/public
- localhost/laravel/myproject/
- localhost/laravel/myproject/public

Did i miss something, i am quite surprised to fix things for hours to use a popular framework like laravel.

Comment: What you'll get at the end? And give full URL of project folder!!

Comment: This is my path to my public folder of laravel  C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\pro\dev\server\xampp\htdocs\projects\perso\laraveltest\loginpage\public                                                                                       The folder loginpage is where i have installed my project in stackoverflow i refer to it by MYPROJECT, when i test it i have a HTTP 404 ERROR.

Comment: Please check this link:-https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8129

Comment: @franckyfranck  You got a very deep structure. I recommend you to use virtual host for this situation. This is where you can start with [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4WfrmKNhj4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4WfrmKNhj4) or another option you can Homestead [http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)

Comment: @anant kumar singh so you think it could be a recent bug, i remember i installed laravel already on xampp some month ago and it worked well but this time i have no idea what happened.

Comment: @mininoz thank you i will try to do that for the moment so Homestead is advice by laravel i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of my question we conclude that laravel has a bug with xampp and the bug was reported 3 days ago on the official bug tracking forum from laravel

- Please check this link: http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8129

Also we have found that my folder structure is too long and it could generate conflict within the configuration of xampp, the advice was to use a virtual host solution, the one advised by laravel is Homestead, so let's try with homestead !

- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead

Good luck to everyone who need to fix their xampp server to work with laravel maybe try to use another webserver instead.

Comment: man homestead is a pain in the ass to make it work i am gonna reopen my question until i find out how to fix the problem on XAMPP server under windows